# Is it OK to call a service inside a ViewModel property using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to figure out how to properly set up my c# MVVM WPF app. I am having trouble understanding how I use the pieces of Model, View, and View Model. I am trying to keep my models dumb. How do you handle a single property like Volume? Creating a model didn't make sense for one property.

I am loading the value from the system. Right now in the view model I am using a service to get and set the volume. I made a property so that I can get and set it which calls the service. This seems like it is probably a bad practice, but I cant think of a good way around it.

Here is an example of a property I am using in the viewmodel so that I can bind to the Volume in the View.

```
public float Volume
{
   get { _volume = audio.GetMasterVolume(); return _volume; }
   set { _volume = value; audio.SetMasterVolume(value); Changed("Volume"); }
}
```

If I instead set up a model to hold the Volume property it seems even more like a pass through. I am very new to this and would love to know the proper way to go about it.

Comment: Not sure of the question.  Your example is correct for a view model.

Comment: I guess I just wanted to know if it is ok to call a service inside the property getter setter.

Comment: _"I am trying to keep my models dumb.""_ Model represents your business logic, the core of your application. It's the opposite of dumb. You write an application to solve a specific problem, this is the model including servicers and data persistence. View model only prepares or exposes data for the view and sends manipulated data back to the model. View presents data to the user reading from the view model and allows user to manipulate data which is send back to the view model.

Comment: You would generally prefer to trigger long running model operations like service interactions using the ICommand. To delegate a property value of the view model directly to the model is generally fine. You simply don't want the view to interact with the model directly.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem here at all, I'd like to rewrite the property to skip the `_volume` member variable.

```
public float Volume
{
    get => audio.GetMasterVolume();
    set => 
    {
        audio.SetMasterVolume(value); 
        Changed(nameof(Volume));
     }
}
```

The only thing one could argue is an anti-pattern is the property calling methods internally. Because most developers using your view model will expect a property to read internal values and may not be aware that reading or writing your property is going to talk to an external service.

If your app allows logic like this, you could listen for volume changes permanently and take that value to a member variable (maybe the one I eliminated in the code above) and return in the property getter. It's just my opinion but I think setting a volume property is expected to do anything externally and does not need to be handled anywhere else than in the setter.

```
/* pseudo code */

ctor()
{
    audio.VolumeChanged += VolumeChanged;
}

private void VolumeChanged(object sender, VolumeEventArgs args)
{
    _volume = args.Volume;
}

public float Volume
{
    get => _volume;
    set => 
    {
        audio.SetMasterVolume(value);  // should set _volume by the event again
        Changed(nameof(Volume));
     }
}
```